# Node fs.unlink doesn't delete file from physical storage

Tags: node.js, fs

Using nodeJS on Window, Node fs.unlink does not delete a file from the machines storage.

When using fs.unlinkSync(fileName), it seems to work.

After the unlinkSync statement is executed, followed by fs.existsSync(filename) it returns false indicating the file does not exist.

However, when I go to the physical drive I can still see the file.

The file is automatically removed from the file system when I stop the currently executing node script.

Is this expected behavior?

How would I delete the file immediately from the devices physical storage?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the file is locked by your application. You should flush and close it before you try to delete.

You think it's possible?